# How to get access to Julia function calling it from matlab engine using MATLAB.jl

Tags: matlab, julia

I have a problem with calling julia functions from matlab engine using  [MATLAB.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/MATLAB.jl).

In my project I have specific function which I must call outside of the engine.

In the simpliest form this problem can be demonstrated like this:

```
using MATLAB

function julia_func(arg::Integer)
  return arg
end

@matlab begin
  ans = exp(julia_func(3))
end

@mget ans
@show ans
```

After performing this code I get:

> Undefined function or variable 'julia_func'.

How to make this work?

Comment: the `@matlab` macro uses *matlab* functions and variables, not Julia functions. If you want to call Julia from matlab, see https://github.com/twadleigh/jlcall